# How to search a given string in XML?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, xml-attribute

I have a XML like:

```
<bodyText>
  <1 beginIndex="0" endIndex="723">
    The teddy bear is a soft toy in the form of a bear. Teddy bears are among the most popular gifts for children and are often given to adults to signify love, congratulations or sympathy.</1>

<2 beginIndex="724" endIndex="347">
    Morris Michtom saw the drawing of Roosevelt and was inspired to create a new toy. He created a little stuffed bear cub and put it in his shop window with a sign that read "Teddy's bear," after sending a bear to Roosevelt and receiving permission to use his name. 
</2>
</bodyText>
```

how do i search particular string in XML ?
For ex: If a user enters "drawing of Roosevelt". The 2nd xml element contains this string and it should return 2(it should return paragraph no).
How to find out ?

Comment: Invalid xml (node names cannot be numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert xml to an internal class, lets call it MyEntry that has id ( the 1 and 2 values in your example, but put them as attribute, the name of the node is irrelevant, put "a" ), beginIndex, endIndex and value (your string) and put a method inside MyEntry in it like:

```
public function search( string:String ):Boolean
{
    return value.indexOf( string ) != -1;
}

//When you search for the string "drawing of Roosevelt":
for each( var entry:MyEntry in entries )
{
    if( entry.search( string ) )
    {
       trace( "Found!" );
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am new to Flex and XML. I don't know about JSON. It would be good to hear new language jargon.

Comment: json is very light weight, native flash encoding/decoding, its test like xml and its converted into flash object/number/string/boolean, etc.